# Power Automate Workflow Send HTTP Request - Cannot handle the data at position 113

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, power-automate

I have created a WorkFlow using Power Automate which fires when a SharePoint site list item is created, it performs the following actions:

1. Collects the values of some of the fields in the newly created list item.
2. Save the values in variables
3. Creates a sub-site using the values in the variables
4. Updates the list item with the URL of the newly created sub-site.

The problem occurs trying to update the list item, (step 4). The list 'Project List' has the following columns:

Title - Single line text field
Subject - Single line of text
ProjectId - Unique number field
ProjectSite - Hyperlink field

Here's the code in the step which is trying to update the list item:

```
    {
    "inputs": {
        "host": {
            "connectionName": "shared_sharepointonline",
            "operationId": "HttpRequest",
            "apiId": "/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_sharepointonline"
        },
        "parameters": {
            "dataset": "https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/VIIProjects",
            "parameters/method": "POST",
            "parameters/uri": "_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Project List')/items(@{triggerOutputs()?['body/ID']})",
            "parameters/headers": {
                "Accept ": "application/json;odata=verbose ",
                "Content-Type ": "application/json;odata=verbose ",
                "IF-MATCH": "*",
                "X-HTTP-METHOD ": "MERGE"
            },
            "parameters/body": "{ '__metadata':
            { 
                'type':'SP.Data.Project_x0020_ListListItem' }, 
                'ProjectSite':{'__metadata':{type:'SP.FieldUrlValue'}, 
                    'Description':'@{variables('SiteTitle')}',
                    'Url':'https://mysite.sharepoint.com@{variables('SiteURL')}'
            }
            } "
        },
        "authentication": "@parameters('$authentication')"
    }
}
```

This step receives the following error:

```
{
  "status": 400,
  "message": "Cannot handle the data at position 113.\r\nclientRequestId: b6d8145e-fce7-4d46-96d5-cd6e110a95ad\r\nserviceRequestId: 86eb819f-d0ea-2000-59b2-7e44fa52ac23",
  "source": "https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/VIIProjects/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Project%20List')/items(4)",
  "errors": [
    "-1",
    "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException"
  ]
}
```

If I browse to mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/VIIProjects/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Project%20List')/items(4) I can see the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<entry xml:base="https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/VIIProjects/_api/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" m:etag="&quot;1&quot;">
  <id>71408e64-5cfa-4099-a02b-e35e16a66ab5</id>
  <category term="SP.Data.Project_x0020_ListListItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
  <link rel="edit" href="Web/Lists(guid'0f5bf3fe-2f8a-41ab-9499-48345eb514f2')/Items(4)" />
  <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/FirstUniqueAncestorSecurableObject" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="FirstUniqueAncestorSecurableObject" href="Web/Lists(guid'0f5bf3fe-2f8a-41ab-9499-48345eb514f2')/Items(4)/FirstUniqueAncestorSecurableObject" />
  <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/RoleAssignments" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="RoleAssignments" href="Web/Lists(guid'0f5bf3fe-2f8a-41ab-9499-48345eb514f2')/Items(4)/RoleAssignments" />
  <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/AttachmentFiles" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="AttachmentFiles" href="Web/Lists(guid'0f5bf3fe-2f8a-41ab-9499-48345eb514f2')/Items(4)/AttachmentFiles" />
  <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/ContentType" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="ContentType" href="Web/Lists(guid'0f5bf3fe-2f8a-41ab-9499-48345eb514f2')/Items(4)/ContentType" />
  <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/GetDlpPolicyTip" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="GetDlpPolicyTip" href="Web/Lists(guid'0f5bf3fe-2f8a-41ab-9499-48345eb514f2')/Items(4)/GetDlpPolicyTip" />
  <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/FieldValuesAsHtml" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="FieldValuesAsHtml" href="Web/Lists(guid'0f5bf3fe-2f8a-41ab-9499-48345eb514f2')/Items(4)/FieldValuesAsHtml" />
  <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/FieldValuesAsText" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="FieldValuesAsText" href="Web/Lists(guid'0f5bf3fe-2f8a-41ab-9499-48345eb514f2')/Items(4)/FieldValuesAsText" />
  <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/FieldValuesForEdit" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="FieldValuesForEdit" href="Web/Lists(guid'0f5bf3fe-2f8a-41ab-9499-48345eb514f2')/Items(4)/FieldValuesForEdit" />
  <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/File" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="File" href="Web/Lists(guid'0f5bf3fe-2f8a-41ab-9499-48345eb514f2')/Items(4)/File" />
  <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Folder" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="Folder" href="Web/Lists(guid'0f5bf3fe-2f8a-41ab-9499-48345eb514f2')/Items(4)/Folder" />
  <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/LikedByInformation" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="LikedByInformation" href="Web/Lists(guid'0f5bf3fe-2f8a-41ab-9499-48345eb514f2')/Items(4)/LikedByInformation" />
  <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/ParentList" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="ParentList" href="Web/Lists(guid'0f5bf3fe-2f8a-41ab-9499-48345eb514f2')/Items(4)/ParentList" />
  <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Properties" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="Properties" href="Web/Lists(guid'0f5bf3fe-2f8a-41ab-9499-48345eb514f2')/Items(4)/Properties" />
  <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Versions" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Versions" href="Web/Lists(guid'0f5bf3fe-2f8a-41ab-9499-48345eb514f2')/Items(4)/Versions" />
  <title />
  <updated>2020-10-09T10:55:13Z</updated>
  <author>
    <name />
  </author>
  <content type="application/xml">
    <m:properties>
      <d:FileSystemObjectType m:type="Edm.Int32">0</d:FileSystemObjectType>
      <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">4</d:Id>
      <d:ServerRedirectedEmbedUri m:null="true" />
      <d:ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl></d:ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl>
      <d:ContentTypeId>0x010023C27C491F3F834B84F6AD1AC5A271BA</d:ContentTypeId>
      <d:Title>1004 - Swansea Nuclear Medicine Website</d:Title>
      <d:ComplianceAssetId m:null="true" />
      <d:cocz>Create an informational website for Swansea Nuclear Medicine</d:cocz>
      <d:vnml m:type="Edm.Double">1004</d:vnml>
      <d:ProjectSite m:null="true" />
      <d:ID m:type="Edm.Int32">4</d:ID>
      <d:Modified m:type="Edm.DateTime">2020-10-09T08:26:56Z</d:Modified>
      <d:Created m:type="Edm.DateTime">2020-10-09T08:26:56Z</d:Created>
      <d:AuthorId m:type="Edm.Int32">6</d:AuthorId>
      <d:EditorId m:type="Edm.Int32">6</d:EditorId>
      <d:OData__UIVersionString>1.0</d:OData__UIVersionString>
      <d:Attachments m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:Attachments>
      <d:GUID m:type="Edm.Guid">f9213fe6-b6a8-403b-8f5d-a8d8e35618ee</d:GUID>
    </m:properties>
  </content>
</entry>
```

Could someone point me in the right direction please.

Many Thanks.

Comment: One question, can't you use "PATCH" method when you updating a list item? I just tested with "PATCH" and it worked. If you would like, I can post a screenshot on that

Comment: Hi Matiur, thanks for your suggestion, I had already tried that. I've now found the solution, the problem was being caused by spaces after the header keys, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after many attempts I finally got it to work. The problem was being caused by the paremeters/headers keys (Accept, Content-Type, and X-HTTP-METHOD), if you look at the keys they have a space after them before the closing double quotes, delete the space and it then works.

**Before - Not Working**

```
   {
    "inputs": {
        "host": {
            "connectionName": "shared_sharepointonline",
            "operationId": "HttpRequest",
            "apiId": "/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_sharepointonline"
        },
        "parameters": {
            "dataset": "https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/VIIProjects",
            "parameters/method": "POST",
            "parameters/uri": "_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Project List')/items(@{triggerOutputs()?['body/ID']})",
            "parameters/headers": {
                "Accept ": "application/json;odata=verbose ",
                "Content-Type ": "application/json;odata=verbose ",
                "IF-MATCH": "*",
                "X-HTTP-METHOD ": "MERGE"
            },
            "parameters/body": "{ '__metadata':
            { 
                'type':'SP.Data.Project_x0020_ListListItem' }, 
                'ProjectSite':{'__metadata':{type:'SP.FieldUrlValue'}, 
                    'Description':'@{variables('SiteTitle')}',
                    'Url':'https://mysite.sharepoint.com@{variables('SiteURL')}'
            }
            } "
        },
        "authentication": "@parameters('$authentication')"
    }
}
```

**After - Working**

```
   {
    "inputs": {
        "host": {
            "connectionName": "shared_sharepointonline",
            "operationId": "HttpRequest",
            "apiId": "/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_sharepointonline"
        },
        "parameters": {
            "dataset": "https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/VIIProjects",
            "parameters/method": "POST",
            "parameters/uri": "_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Project List')/items(@{triggerOutputs()?['body/ID']})",
            "parameters/headers": {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "IF-MATCH": "*",
                "X-HTTP-METHOD": "MERGE"
            },
            "parameters/body": "{ '__metadata':
            { 
                'type':'SP.Data.Project_x0020_ListListItem' }, 
                'ProjectSite':{'__metadata':{type:'SP.FieldUrlValue'}, 
                    'Description':'@{variables('SiteTitle')}',
                    'Url':'https://mysite.sharepoint.com@{variables('SiteURL')}'
            }
            } "
        },
        "authentication": "@parameters('$authentication')"
    }
}
```

Hopefully this will help someone else with a similar problem.